# turfjs intersect line and polygon

Tags: intersection, turf

In old turfjs versions, it was possible to intersect a line and a polygon, like in [this example](https://bl.ocks.org/danswick/4a282503825358125b06).

But changing the turf.js version to the last one makes it fail, as shown in [this other example](https://bl.ocks.org/rveciana/62367908105448366d38f169e5bd3893).

[The docs say](http://turfjs.org/docs#intersect) that the *intersect* function works only with two polygons, so the error is documented.

Is it possible to use some other function to do that? Is there any example around there showing how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

==EDIT==

A better soulution, that works with multilinestrings and multiple intersections, is using [lineSplit](http://turfjs.org/docs#lineSplit), as shown in [this example](https://bl.ocks.org/rveciana/e0565ca3bfcebedb12bbc2d4edb9b6b3). 
Just iterate through the splitted lines and take only one each two of them.

---

I found the answer, which is combining [lineIntersect](http://turfjs.org/docs/#lineIntersect) and [lineSlice](http://turfjs.org/docs/#lineSlice):

```
let intersectionPoints = turf.lineIntersect(line, poly);
let intersectionPointsArray = intersectionPoints.features.map(d => {return d.geometry.coordinates});

let intersection = turf.lineSlice(turf.point(intersectionPointsArray[0]), turf.point(intersectionPointsArray[1]), line);
```

As I mention in the example, this will work with only one part of the line intersecting the polygon. If the line goes in and out several times, the method must be applied as many times as needed.

Comment: I was playing with JSTS instead. As you seem to work only with Turf, I put the example link just as an addition https://bl.ocks.org/ThomasG77/d66f1040960646abf56c90ae5e759b8a

Comment: @ThomasG77 Thank you. It works better. I'm trying to use it with ES6 but I can't find how. A similar solution like this doesn't work: https://github.com/DenisCarriere/jsts-es6-example/blob/master/es6-examples/buffer.js

Comment: Try https://codesandbox.io/s/0m4mj899rv Same version as before but ES6 based (took some shortcuts but enough for the demonstration)

Comment: The problem is that the import { io } from "jsts"; part doesn't work. All the examples I see use something like import GeoJSONReader from 'jsts/org/locationtech/jts/io/GeoJSONReader', but then, the intersection function does not exist.

Comment: "The problem is that the import { io } from "jsts"; part doesn't work" Not sure why you are saying that. It works on my side (using Google Chrome). For `import GeoJSONReader from 'jsts/org/locationtech/jts/io/GeoJSONReader'`, like you, I was also not able to make it works (I thinkd related to the fact Node vs browser/webpack context)

Comment: Thank you. I finally got it in Turf, but definitly will look more jsts. I used this path because I'm integrating it in React, and the first option didn't work...

Comment: This solution only works when the line goes in and out from the polygon... If the line just enters the polygon it returns the error `throw new Error("coordinates is required")`... https://jsfiddle.net/raylight/dx780Lou/

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at TurfJs **lineOverlap**: https://turfjs.org/docs/#lineOverlap. From the docs:

```
"Takes any LineString or Polygon and returns the overlapping lines between both features."
```

From my understanding the overlap of polygon and a line is the part of the line which is inside the polygon.

Comment: I think lineOverlap is to find lines the two geometries in have in common, different than intersection.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this today at work, an example with modern turf

```js
/**
 *
 * @param {LineString | MultiLineString} lineOrMultiLine input line or multiline
 * @param {Polygon | MultiPolygon} polygonOrMultiPolygon input polygon or multipolygon
 * @returns {FeatureCollection} a multiLineString with all the lines inside the polygon
 */

function linesInPolygon(lineOrMultiLine, polygonOrMultiPolygon) {
  // because line split does not accept multiLineString we flatten in case there are multilines
  const lines = turf.flatten(lineOrMultiLine);
  const linesInside = [];
  for (const line of lines.features) {
    // split line by polygon
    const split = turf.lineSplit(line, polygonOrMultiPolygon);
    for (const part of split.features) {
      // check which parts have a start inside the polygon
      const start = turf.booleanPointInPolygon(
        turf.point(part.geometry.coordinates[0]),
        polygonOrMultiPolygon
      );
      if (start) {
        linesInside.push(part);
      }
    }
  }
  // return as a featureCollection of lines
  return turf.featureCollection(linesInside);
}
```

#### ESM Version:

```js
import lineSplit from '@turf/line-split';
import { point, featureCollection } from '@turf/helpers';
import booleanPointInPolygon from '@turf/boolean-point-in-polygon';
import flatten from '@turf/flatten';

/**
 *
 * @param {LineString | MultiLineString} lineOrMultiLine input line or multiline
 * @param {Polygon | MultiPolygon} polygonOrMultiPolygon input polygon or multipolygon
 * @returns {FeatureCollection} a multiLineString with all the lines inside the polygon
 */
export function linesInPolygon(lineOrMultiLine, polygonOrMultiPolygon) {
  // because line split does not accept multiLineString we flatten in case there are multilines
  const lines = flatten(lineOrMultiLine);
  const linesInside = [];
  for (const line of lines.features) {
    // split line by polygon
    const split = lineSplit(line, polygonOrMultiPolygon);
    for (const part of split.features) {
      // check which parts have a start inside the polygon
      const start = booleanPointInPolygon(
        point(part.geometry.coordinates[0]),
        polygonOrMultiPolygon
      );
      if (start) {
        linesInside.push(part);
      }
    }
  }
  // return as a featureCollection of lines
  return featureCollection(linesInside);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Turf used to use the JSTS package to find the intersection, but switched over at some point.

An example with JSTS:

```typescript
import { GeometryObject } from 'geojson';
import * as jsts from 'jsts';

export function intersect(geom1: GeometryObject, geom2: GeometryObject) {

  const reader = new jsts.io.GeoJSONReader();
  const jstsGeometry1 = reader.read(geom1);
  const jstsGeometry2 = reader.read(geom2);

  const intersection = getIntersection(jstsGeometry1, jstsGeometry2);
  if (hasIntersection(intersection)) {
    const writer = new jsts.io.GeoJSONWriter();
    return writer.write(intersection) as GeometryObject;
  } else {
    return undefined;
  }
}


function getIntersection(geom1: jsts.geom.Geometry, geom2: jsts.geom.Geometry) {
  try {
    return geom1.intersection(geom2);
  } catch (ex) {
    if (ex?.name === 'TopologyException') {
      // Self-intersecting polygons are not supported. We handle this as 'no intersection'
      return undefined;
    }

    throw ex;
  }
}

function hasIntersection(jstsGeometry: jsts.geom.Geometry) {
  return jstsGeometry != null && jstsGeometry.getCoordinates().length > 0;
}
```